Why is Clang adding underscore suffixes to Objective-C parameter names in autogenerated headers
I had a Swift method with a parameter called module. I noticed that the [Project]-Swift.h autogenerated header renamed that parameter to module_ in the Objective-C signature for that method. After some more investigation, it looks like this is happening for C++ keywords:
@objcMembers class SomeClass: NSObject {
    func someMethod(init: String) {}

    // ↓ These will append an underscore in the header file.
    func someMethod(template: String) {}
    func someMethod(consteval: String) {}
}

becomes:
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC9iOSTester9SomeClass")
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
- (void)someMethodWithInit:(NSString * _Nonnull)init;
- (void)someMethodWithTemplate:(NSString * _Nonnull)template_;
- (void)someMethodWithConsteval:(NSString * _Nonnull)consteval_;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end

Is this documented behaviour of the compiler or just some implementation detail? Why would it be necessary?

Some people compile source code with Objective-C++.  Probably to avoid keyword collisions, is my guess.

Standard C++ name mangling?

Reduced  too much code for demonstrating the question object.

It is not renaming the parameters at all. In Objective-C, the parameter name is part of the method name. In someMethodWithTemplate:, the Template part is the parameter name, based directly on your template but with an initial capital letter, which is standard convention and part of "renamification". The template_ you are asking about is merely an internal name, and is effectively meaningless (it is thrown away and affects nothing).

Why do you care how Objective-C header is generated? That module_ doesn't used anywhere.  For me it looks like as minor bag. You can report it if you want.
